# Applications' tray icons aren't displayed in Linux Mint 17 on Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, icons, tray

I've installed Linux Mint 17 with Cinnamon.

I tried to make GNote, Thunderbird and Skype autorun on system startup minimized to tray. I made them autoruned with `Startup application` program. Then I made GNote and Skype minimize into tray with their menu settings. And I had to install a couple of add-ons(`MinimizeToTray revived` and `firetray`. because the former didn't work) on Thinderbird to make it minimizable to tray.

After that at first it worked first time but then a strange bug appeared. Every time I minimize one of these programs to tray or they are minimized with startup their tray icons don't appear. They appear to be working in processes list, but no tray icon and no icon on panel as well. So it actually gets to tray but no icon appears on the other hand.

Is there any way explain it and repair the tray? Tray worked but then it got broken in that way.

Answer (score -1):

These changes to the systray js file may help
https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/commit/d1a9cbd8dba2187230b0949b9b6d1e19cefe17e9
https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/commit/4aabc5a4944d9d7c864e47b971ca252431781ac0

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.